# TextView under expandableList disappears

Tags: java, android

When there is not much data list of ListView, TextView can be seen well. But when there is a lot of data and the List fills the screen, TextView written test disappears. Please see the picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm7OS.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M76Mv.jpg)

Here is the code source.
https://github.com/hardcodingJeon/ExpandList_recyclerView

thankyou!

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ExpandableListView listView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Display newDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = newDisplay.getWidth();

        ArrayList<GroupItem> DataList = new ArrayList<>();
        listView = (ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.mylist);

        for (int i=1;i<25;i++) {
            GroupItem temp = new GroupItem("A"+i);
            temp.childItems.add(new GroupItem.ChildItem("1","2"));
            temp.childItems.add(new GroupItem.ChildItem("2","3"));
            temp.childItems.add(new GroupItem.ChildItem("4","5"));
            DataList.add(temp);
        }



        ExpandAdapter adapter = new ExpandAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.group_row, R.layout.activity_child, DataList);
        listView.setIndicatorBounds(width - 50, width); 
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

**ExpandAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ExpandAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int groupLayout = 0;
    private int chlidLayout = 0;
    private ArrayList<GroupItem> DataList;
    private LayoutInflater myinf = null;

    public ExpandAdapter(Context context,int groupLay,int chlidLay,ArrayList<GroupItem> DataList){
        this.context = context;
        this.groupLayout = groupLay;
        this.chlidLayout = chlidLay;
        this.DataList = DataList;
        this.myinf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = myinf.inflate(this.groupLayout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView groupName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupName);
        groupName.setText(DataList.get(groupPosition).groupTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = myinf.inflate(this.chlidLayout, parent, false);
        }
        RecyclerView recyclerView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(context,DataList.get(groupPosition).childItems);
        LinearLayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DataList.get(groupPosition).childItems.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public GroupItem getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DataList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return DataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

}
```

**GroupItem.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class GroupItem {
    public String groupTitle;
    public ArrayList<ChildItem> childItems = new ArrayList<>();

    public GroupItem(String groupTitle) {
        this.groupTitle = groupTitle;
    }

    public static class ChildItem {
        String beforePrice;
        String afterPrice;

        public ChildItem(String beforePrice, String afterPrice) {
            this.beforePrice = beforePrice;
            this.afterPrice = afterPrice;
        }
    }
}
```

**RecyclerAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<GroupItem.ChildItem> items;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GroupItem.ChildItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    //뷰id를 참조함
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item,parent,false);  
        VH holder = new VH(itemView);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        VH vh = (VH)holder; 

        
        GroupItem.ChildItem item = items.get(position);

       
        vh.beforePrice.setText( item.beforePrice );
        vh.afterPrice.setText( item.afterPrice );
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView beforePrice;
        TextView afterPrice;
        Button btn;

        public VH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            beforePrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_item_beforePrice);
            afterPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.child_item_afterPrice);
            btn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, items.get(getLayoutPosition()).beforePrice+"\n"+items.get(getLayoutPosition()).afterPrice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indicatorRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorRight"
                android:id="@+id/mylist" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEST"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_child.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**child_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:contentPaddingTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/child_item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="월간유니콘\nPLUS 31"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/child_item_period"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1 개월간 매일 2회"
            android:layout_below="@id/child_item_title"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/child_item_Linear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/child_item_period"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="정기구독"
                android:layout_below="@id/child_item_period"/>

            <!--data-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/child_item_beforePrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="62000원"/>

            <!--data-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/child_item_afterPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="29000/월"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="구매"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/child_item_Linear"
            android:layout_below="@id/child_item_period"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**child_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/childName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:paddingLeft="40dip"
        />
    <CheckBox
        android:textColor="#111111"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New CheckBox"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**group_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/groupName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5px"
        android:textColor = "#FFA500"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have set the ExpandableListView height as wrap content. Hence when the no of elements increase it pushes the TextView below the available screen . I would suggest
1.using ConstraintLayout or RelativeLayout
2. Affixing the TextView at the very bottom and then arranging your Expandable list view relative to that

Otherwise set the height of Expandable ListView to a particular predetermined value(Not Adviced) and it should work perfectly